# Where do I save token in Power BI web connection?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI, and starting to use the "From Web" data source. It works great.

But where do I save tokens, so I don't have to provide them as plain-text in every web connection?

[image]

I don't seem to find any documentation on variables to do this.

Answer (score 2):

First step is to create a token parameter:
[image]

Now open the Advanced Editor, and refrence the token param from above:

[image]

In my case, the headers section uses the bearer token pattern:

```
[Headers=[Authorization="Bearer " & token]]
```

And ready to roll :)