# How do I retrieve a bearer token from a service in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, webapi

I am attempting to call a web API-- say, `https://myresources/getresources`. This call requires an API Key, resourcesApiKey and a bearer token. The token must be acquired from another service, `https://mytokenservice/jwt`. It requires an API key, tokenServiceApiKey.

I'm able to get my resource data by manually accessing the token service and entering values, but I'd like to have Power BI take care of all this for me. I read something about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60056709/where-do-i-save-token-in-power-bi-web-connection), but this seems to apply to a static token. Ours changes, so I need to actually call out to this service.

So, what I'm trying to do is this:

1. Save a token service url and API key with my report. When the report is run, Power BI should use the url and key to retrieve a bearer token.
2. Save a resources API url and api key with my report. Apply the bearer token retrieved in step 1, along with the resources API key to calls made to the resource API url to retrieve the data I'm really after.

I think the approach described [here](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/03/26/working-with-web-services-in-power-query/) applies, but I can't get it to work. Here's what I most recently tried using the Power BI advanced editor:

- I created a parameter in Power BI using Manage Parameters, then used Advanced Editor, I entered the following:

  Web.Content(
  "`https://mytokenservice/jwt`",
  [
  ApiKeyName="tokenServiceApiKey"
  ]
  )

I also created Power BI parameters for tokenServiceApiKey and resourcesApiKey that contain the key for each.

When I clicked "Done" in the Advanced Editor, though, it automatically generated some code around what I'd written, so that it now reads,

```
Html.Table(Web.Content("https://mytokenservice/jwt",[ApiKeyName="tokenServiceApiKey"]), {})
```

What appears in the editor is a table icon containing no data. I should be getting a string back. I don't know where to go from here and am having trouble finding answers online.

Is there anyway to accomplish what I'm after?

I probably haven't explained it very well, so please ask questions if you need more information or clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Number-1: You can build your own data connector for your purpose. Some guidelines will find here- [Click Here](https://www.sqlgene.com/2019/02/19/create-a-power-query-custom-data-connector-in-10-minutes/)

NUmber-2: You can also use power query to connect your source. Recently I have collected data for clients using oAuth2 API. You can connect to any API using Power/M Query. Following is the sample code for my case, where in the first part I have collected the access_token and in second step, I have collected data using that access token. hope this will give you some idea on connecting to any API using Power Query.

```
let
    url = "your_authentication_url_here",

    body  = "{ ""client_id"": ""****"",  ""client_secret"": ""****"", ""grant_type"": ""****"", ""audience"":""****""}",
    tokenResponse = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,[Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/json"], Content = Text.ToBinary(body) ] )),
    AccessToken = tokenResponse[access_token],
    AccessTokenHeader = "Bearer " & AccessToken,


    data_url = "your_main_url_here",
    data_body = "{
                    ""authorization"": """& AccessTokenHeader & """,
                    ""content-type"": ""application/json""
                }",

    GetGroups = Json.Document(
        Web.Contents(
            data_url, 
            [
                Headers = Json.Document(data_body)
            ] 
        )
    ),    

    categories = GetGroups[categories], --Category here will be changed as per your retrned data

    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(categories, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn
    (
        #"Converted to Table", "Column1", 
        {"ext_id", "shared", "report", "query", "_id", "description"}, --This is column returned from your data set
        {"ext_id", "shared", "report", "query", "_id", "description"}  -- Rename columns accordingly
    )
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. It helped me get part 2 working (calling the resource API), but only with a hard-coded token. The reason for this is that I still cannot access the bearer token API, even though I'm using a similar approach--i.e., I just created header content as you did for "your_main_url_here" and set it equal to the bearer token call's Headers parameter. I receive this message: "We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided." So it's almost working.

Comment: With this same code, I am dynamically collecting bearer access token and data from second step. You may need some adjustments as per your API setup.

Comment: Is "access_token" a property of a token response?

Comment: Yes and you have to add the word bearer before the token manually as you see in the code.

Comment: My problem seems to be that in the call to the token service, we use Windows Auth with an "api-key" header. When I try to do this, I get a power BI exception that states the following: "Expression.Error: The 'api-key' header is only supported when connecting anonymously. These headers can be used with all authentication types: Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Cache-Control, Content-Type, If-Modified-Since, Prefer, Range, Referer"

Comment: Did you tried with Custom connector (Option-1)? there you will get some more control over the whole process.

Comment: Not yet, but I will, since I'm stumped with the current approach.

Comment: I looked into custom connectors but can't find anything suggesting that what I'm after is possible with that approach, either. I'm going to mark your response as the answer since it got me halfway there and open a new question with the particulars of what's blocking me now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are most welcome @RobC. Hope you will get your solution soon.

Comment: I can provide you a sample code written for Custom Connector which is working for me. I have connected to an API data source there using Bearer Token.

Comment: Does the API data source use Windows Authentication and require a header that isn't on PBI's list of "allowed" headers? If so, I'd love to see it.

Comment: It depends, how your API configured.

Comment: @RobC did you ever get a custom header working with Windows Auth?  An example I'm facing is that neither Content, nor method="POST" are allowed in the Power Query built in connectors, which means no post requests with windows auth can be used.

Hoping the custom connector will allow this, and like you was hoping to see an example. I feel post requests against windows auth would be very common in an enterprise environment? Projects built with C# handle post requests against windows auth just fine so I'm surprised and frustrated that Power Query disallows post requests against windows auth.