# How do I send a custom header using Power BI when Windows Authorization is required?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am attempting to use Power BI (Power Query) to access a bearer token API that uses Windows Authentication and requires an api key header. The problem I'm running into is that Power BI accepts only certain headers. When I attempt to include my organization's "api-key" header, I receive the following error message:

```
Expression.Error: The 'api-key' header is only supported when connecting anonymously. These headers can be used with all authentication types: Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Cache-Control, Content-Type, If-Modified-Since, Prefer, Range, Referer
```

The code I'm using looks something like this, though I've tried several variations:

```
let

    securityTokenServiceUrl = "https://mysecurityservice",
    myApiKey = "123456789",
    securityHeader = "{
        ""accept"": ""text/plain"",
        ""api-key"": """& myApiKey & """
    }",
    tokenResponse = Json.Document(Web.Contents(securityTokenServiceUrl, [
        Headers = Json.Document(securityHeader)
        ])),
    token = tokenResponse[access_token]

in
    token
```

I've done a lot of looking around, but can only find suggestions on how to do this with Anonymous authorization, not with Windows Auth, as I need. I tried using a custom data connector as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63400612/how-do-i-retrieve-a-bearer-token-from-a-service-in-power-bi), but cannot seem to get it working. Is there any way to get around this restriction and pass along my api key header as described above?

Comment: Hi @RobC, its me again :) is your link "https://mysecurityservice" up? I am getting the error- DataSource.Error: The remote name could not be resolved: 'mysecurityservice'

Comment: No, it's not a real URL. The real one is an internal one where I work. Sorry for the confusion. I'm beginning to think that, for some reason, Power BI just doesn't allow custom headers to be used for Windows Auth. I haven't seen any evidence of it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was unable to find a way around this Power BI restriction, I ended up creating a simple Web API that uses Windows Auth with no custom headers. Power BI calls this API, which in turn makes the Windows Auth call (with a custom header) to the service and retrieves the needed bearer token.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same thing. Would you mind sharing your code?

*...a simple Web API that uses Windows Auth with no custom headers. ...*

Comment: @Maxcot There wasn't anything special about the code I used: typical .NET Core web API with WindowsAuth and RestSharp to make the outgoing call.

Comment: :) that may be, but I'm not a professional coder. Could you point me to some actual examples / source code?

Comment: @Maxcot This should get you going with Windows Auth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio, and this should get you going with RestSharp: https://restsharp.dev/getting-started/getting-started.html.

Hope that helps.